# Python receive Google Drive push notification

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

Since the Drive SDK v3 we are able to receive [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) from Google Drive whenever a file has changed. At the moment I'm working on a Drive application in Python and I would like to receive such notifications. Do I really need a web server for this or can I implement this maybe with a socket or something like this?

I know that I can get changes by polling the [changes.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list) method but I want to avoid this because of so many API calls. Is there maybe a better way to get informed if a file has changed?

**EDIT**: I captured my web traffic and saw, that the original Google Drive Client for Windows uses push notifications. So in some way it must be possible to get push notifications in a desktop application but is this maybe some sort of *Google magic* which we can't use with the current API

Answer (score 2):

For [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) apps that need to keep track of changes to files, the [`Changes collection`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes) provides an efficient way to detect changes to all files, including those that have been shared with a user. The collection works by providing the current state of each file, if and only if the file has changed since a given point in time.

Retrieving changes requires a pageToken to indicate a point in time to fetch changes from.

```
# Begin with our last saved start token for this user or the
# current token from getStartPageToken()
page_token = saved_start_page_token;
while page_token is not None:
response = drive_service.changes().list(pageToken=page_token,
fields='*',
spaces='drive').execute()
for change in response.get('changes'):
# Process change
print 'Change found for file: %s' % change.get('fileId')
if 'newStartPageToken' in response:
# Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
saved_start_page_token = response.get('newStartPageToken')
page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
```

Comment: I meant this with _polling the changes.list method_ and I would like to avoid this because of so many API calls in a loop.